# Applying CSS into Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help me out with this. I am trying to apply a CSS Style to this Javascript Code that I have.

I want it to contain Hover/or mouseover the color of the text be white for example and no underline or something like that.

Can someone give me an example of how to do that?

I am a beginner in this and don't know how to make something like this

```js
var links = [
  ['Home', '#1'],
  ['News', '#2'],
  ['Contact', '#3'],
  ['About', '#4']
];

function makeNav( links ) {
  var nav = document.getElementById('myTopnav');
  for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i ++ ) {
    nav.innerHTML += '<a class="nav-link" href="' + links[i][1] + '">' + links[i][0] + '</a>' + ' ';
  }
  return nav;
}

makeNav( links );
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(backgroundimg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#myTopnav {
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, .2);
  height: 40px;
  top: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"></div>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your CSS, you should use some `:hover` selector for your links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, use `:hover` on your links `.nav-link` like this:

```js
var links = [
  ['Home', '#1'],
  ['News', '#2'],
  ['Contact', '#3'],
  ['About', '#4']
];

function makeNav( links ) {
  var nav = document.getElementById('myTopnav');
  for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i ++ ) {
    nav.innerHTML += '<a class="nav-link" href="' + links[i][1] + '">' + links[i][0] + '</a>' + ' ';
  }
  return nav;
}

makeNav( links );
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(backgroundimg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#myTopnav {
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, .2);
  height: 40px;
  top: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"></div>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the style of an element when you hover it does not require any “JavaScript magic”, this is a simple use case of CSS. You can define a class with the [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) peudoselector to change the style of an element when the mouse moves over it.

In your example, this would look something like this:

```
.nav-link:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```js
var links = [
  ['Home', '#1'],
  ['News', '#2'],
  ['Contact', '#3'],
  ['About', '#4']
];

function makeNav( links ) {
  var nav = document.getElementById('myTopnav');
  for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i ++ ) {
    nav.innerHTML += '<a class="nav-link" href="' + links[i][1] + '">' + links[i][0] + '</a>' + ' ';
  }
  return nav;
}

makeNav( links );
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(backgroundimg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#myTopnav {
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, .2);
  height: 40px;
  top: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"></div>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using plain old css.  Note the `a:hover` styles added to the css file.

```js
var links = [
  ['Home', '#1'],
  ['News', '#2'],
  ['Contact', '#3'],
  ['About', '#4']
];

function makeNav( links ) {
  var nav = document.getElementById('myTopnav');
  for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i ++ ) {
    nav.innerHTML += '<a class="nav-link" href="' + links[i][1] + '">' + links[i][0] + '</a>' + ' ';
  }
  return nav;
}

makeNav( links );
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(backgroundimg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#myTopnav {
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, .2);
  height: 40px;
  top: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"></div>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This made my day :)

Comment: This makes all links (not only those you created in JavaScript) turn white when hovering over them.